# How to get rows by a list of ids including repeated ids?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a list of `id`s as

```
1,1,2,3,3,3,1
```

and want to calculate the sum of a column for the above rows. If I use `IN` as

```
SELECT SUM(score) FROM table1 WHERE id IN(1,1,2,3,3,3,1)
```

it will be the sum of three rows (unique ids), but I need to include repeated rows too (7 rows of `1,1,2,3,3,3,1`).

**EDIT:** The table structure is simple. Something like

```
CREATE TABLE table1
(
id int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
score int(11),
PRIMARY KEY (id)
) ENGINE=InnoDB
```

Comment: Can we have a look at the table1 definition GoogleBot? Please

Comment: @zip I added the table structure to the question.

Comment: result for the `WHERE id IN(1,2,3)` and `WHERE id IN(1,1,2,3,3,3,1)` will be same for SUM().

Comment: @DevsiOdedra I know that. This is my question, what should I do instead of `IN` to get `1,1,2,3,3,3,1`.

Answer (score 2):

You need to create a derived table containing those `id` values and then `JOIN` that to your `table1` to generate rows for each instance of a value in your list. Those rows can then be summed:

```
SELECT SUM(score)
FROM (SELECT 1 AS id UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 2 UNION ALL SELECT 3
                     UNION ALL SELECT 3 UNION ALL SELECT 3 UNION ALL SELECT 1) ids
JOIN table1 t1 ON t1.id = ids.id
```

[Demo on dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=150ff838a0dd7ded4caf6ec85e032fc2)

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do this using the `IN` condition, because `IN` treats your items as a set (i.e. ensures uniqueness).

You can produce the desired result by joining to a `UNION ALL`, like this:

> 1,1,2,3,3,3,1

```
SELECT SUM(Score)
FROM Table_1 t
JOIN ( SELECT 1 AS ID
       UNION ALL SELECT 1 AS ID
       UNION ALL SELECT 2 AS ID
       UNION ALL SELECT 3 AS ID
       UNION ALL SELECT 3 AS ID
       UNION ALL SELECT 3 AS ID
       UNION ALL SELECT 1 AS ID
 ) x ON x.ID = t.ID
```

Or

```
CREATE TABLE #TempIDs
(
   ID int
)
INSERT INTO #TempIDs (1)
INSERT INTO #TempIDs (1)
INSERT INTO #TempIDs (2)
INSERT INTO #TempIDs (3)
INSERT INTO #TempIDs (3)
INSERT INTO #TempIDs (3)
INSERT INTO #TempIDs (1)

Select SUM(Score) From Table_1
INNER JOIN #TempIDs t n Table_1.ID = t.ID;
```